# Some elements on meta profiles are black instead of white

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

On a meta profile page, the links to other profiles and the "Moderator" label are colored black instead of white:

[image: Screenshot of Jeff's profile]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build.